# Display the 0 at end of value (Libre Office Calc)

Tags: libreoffice

When I'm creating number values in a column, in **Libre Office Calc**, the 0 number is hidden from the view, if it is at the very end of the number. I'd like to see all of the numbers, even if the last number is a 0. Is there any way to do this?

**Example:**

- What I want it to display, and what I type in: **16.80**
- What is displayed after typing in the number: **16.8**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cell or cells you want to adjust.

If you're handling numbers and need to be able to treat the values as numbers,

- Format cells:
- Numbers
- Category: Number
- Options: Decimal places: 2

If the numbers are actually text (phone numbers, perhaps) then,

- Format cells:
- Text